# JavaScript: string Manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am having a hard time chaining some methods together. Can you please provide some assistance?

The end result should = Mickey MOUSE

```
var name = "MicKEy MOUse";

function nameChanger(oldName) {
    var finalName = oldName;

    var splitString = name.split(' ');

    var fname = splitString.slice(0,1);
    var fname_lower = fname.toLowerCase.slice(1,6);


    return fname_lower;

};
console.log(nameChanger(name));
```

Since I am trying to learn the methods in the function I would appreciate assistance on those items. However, if there are more eloquent ways of performing the same action I would appreciate that input as well.

Thank you in advance for your knowledge and direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Split the name into two, based on the space character

   ```
   var splitString = oldName.split(' ');
   ```
2. Convert the entire first string to lowercase and the second string to uppercase.

   ```
   var fname = splitString[0].toLowerCase();
   var lname = splitString[1].toUpperCase();
   ```
3. Now, just create a new String from `fname`, by changing the first character to upper case, join it with `lname` and return it, like this

   ```
   return fname[0].toUpperCase() + fname.substring(1) + " " + lname;
   ```

So, your complete function would look like this

```
function nameChanger(oldName) {
    var splitString = oldName.split(' ');
    var fname = splitString[0].toLowerCase();
    var lname = splitString[1].toUpperCase();
    return fname[0].toUpperCase() + fname.substring(1) + " " + lname;
};
```

**Note:** You might be wondering, why we are doing this

```
fname[0].toUpperCase() + fname.substring(1)
```

to change just the first character of `fname`. In JavaScript, Strings are immutable objects. Once a String object is created, it can never be changed. So, we are creating a new String object, based on the modified first character of `fname` and the rest of `fname`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = "MicKEy MOUse";

function nameChanger(oldName) {

    var splitString = name.split(' ');

    return splitString[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+splitString[0].slice(1).toLowerCase()+' '+splitString[1].toUpperCase();

};

console.log(nameChanger(name));
```

Expanded code (for Robert Rossmann):

```
var name = "MicKEy MOUse";

function nameChanger(oldName) {

    //Splitting `oldName` to array with words
    var splitString = name.split(' ');

    //Setting variable which contains first word
    var firstWord = splitString[0];

    //Setting variable which contains second word
    var secondWord = splitString[1];

    //Setting variable which contains first letter of first word
    var firstWordLetter = firstWord.charAt(0);

    //Setting variable which contains first word letters, without first letter
    var firstWordRestOfLetters = firstWord.slice(1);

    //Result first word (first letter to upper case, rest of letters to lower case)
    var resultFirstWord = firstWordLetter.toUpperCase()+firstWordRestOfLetters.toLowerCase();

    //Result second word (all second word letters to upper case)
    var resultSecondWord = secondWord.toUpperCase();

    //Returning string with first and second word separated with space
    return resultFirstWord+' '+resultSecondWord;

};
```

Comment: Pieces of code without explanation should be discouraged.

Comment: Edited specially for You.